# std::thread <unresolved overloaded function type> error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, stdthread

I am trying to spawn a thread from within my class and the thread executes a particular method in my class. The code looks like this:

```
class ThreadClass{
    int myThread(int arg){
     // do something
    }

    void createThread(){
        thread t = thread(myThread,10);
    }

} ;
```

This code on compilation throws an error saying

```
std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (ThreadClass::*)(int), _Args = {int}]
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘int (ThreadClass::*&&)(int)’
```

I am not sure what is the actual bug here. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that a member function can't be called without an object. Provide a pointer to `this` so that the current object is used:

```
thread t(&ThreadClass::myThread, this, 10);
```

You could use an instance of any `ThreadClass` object, but in your case, it seems `this` is the right thing to do.

NOTE: Remember you need a reference to the created thread so that you can do a `join()` later on.

Comment: You need a reference to the created thread if you need to do a join() later on.

Comment: I'm sorry, but which thread overload is this?

Comment: @nore This one:
`template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );`.
You can see it here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Comment: O.K., overload 3; but why is this `this` supplied? Isn't that recognized as an argument?

Comment: @nore When calling a member function it is necessary to provide a `this` object. `std::invoke` (the mechanism used to start the thread) uses the first parameter as a `this` for the invocation.

Comment: I don't see any mention of this behavior on the reference page--thank you anyways.